# stringizing #a in define, why is it bad

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print_int(a) printf("%s : %d\n",#a,(a))
int main(void) {
    int y = 10;
    print_int(y);
    return 0;
}
```

i am taking a class and have been asked to explain why this is bad... So i guess stringizing #a is the problem. It does work, so why is it dangerous?

Comment: Whoever gave you that assignment is trying to impose a fringe viewpoint on students. There's no established reason this should be considered bad.

Comment: i am trying to see why it should be bad before having an opinion on the political side of this... i probably would code like that anyways

Comment: I'm not even sure why somebody would consider it bad. I've never heard this cited as a practice "considered harmful" before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it bypasses type safety. What happens when someone hates you and goes `print_int("5412");`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print_int(a) printf("%s : %d\n",#a,(a))
int main(void) {
    print_int("1123123");
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
$ gcc test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’
$ ./a.out 
"1123123" : 3870
```

Comment: C99 for the win: `#define print_int(a) printf("%s : %d\n",#a,(int){a})`

Comment: @Enabren: the warning in your answer is a courtesy of the compiler, whereas the one from my code is an actual violation of C language semantics (see C99 6.5.4 §3) and should probably be an error if `std=c99` is set...

Comment: I don't believe `(int){a}` is a valid compound literal, but I may be mistaken. Of course this would be: `(int [1]){a}[0]`.

Comment: @R., yes, it is a valid compound literal: syntactically these these are described as casts followed by a brace initializer.

Comment: I was under the impression that the set of types valid for compound initializers and the set of those valid for casts were disjoint.

Comment: @R..: initializers can be used to initialize scalar values (`int a = { 42 };` is legal C), and it would be silly to arbitrarily disallow this for compound literals...

Comment: `(int)` is a cast. `(struct foo)` is not a valid cast and therefore it was available as an operator to create a compound literal. If you claim `(int){42}` is valid C, please cite the standard.

Comment: @R..: if you insist: `int` is an object-type which is not a variable-length array type, thus conforming to the constraints imposed by 6.5.2.5 §1; §7 states that the brace-enclosed list must be a legal initializer, and 6.7.8 §11 allows scalar initializers; the standard does not contain any section which would disallow scalar compound literals, and the syntax is unambiguous as a cast operator can't be followed by braces

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's bad at all.  The stringtize operator is very useful for writing macros like assertions:

```
#define assert(x) do { if (!(x)) { printf("assert failed: %s\n", #x); } } while (0)
```

You an abuse any useful feature.  I once had the bright idea to "simplify" Qt Atoms by writing:

```
#define ATOM(x)  (((#x)[0] << 24) | ((#x)[1] << 16) | ...
```

So you could say `ATOM(MPEG)` and get `('M' << 24 | 'P' << 16 | ...)`.  In fact, it worked well enough that gcc could produce integer constants from it...  Sometimes...  Now that was evil!

Comment: The conversion from chars to int is dependent on the endianness, you should encapsulate that in another macro, e.g. `#define FOUR_CHAR_TO_INT(a,b,c,d) ((a)<<24 | (b)<<16 | ... )` and `#define ATOM(x) FOUR_CHAR_TO_INT((#x)[0], (#x)[1], (#x)[2], (#x)[3])`.

Comment: Wonderful way to make your program non-portable: use fake integer constant expressions that gcc treats as if they were valid integer constant expressions.

Comment: @hlovdal: There is no endian-dependency whatsoever in Ben's code.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor statements are generally considered evil. Bad things will happen when I say:

```
int a = 15;
print_int(a++);
```

Comment: Really? Why is the pre-processor evil? It is/can be complex (but powerful), but that is not evil.

Comment: Hm, i guess "evil" is probably not acadmic enough an explanation for uni. I have actually never come across code that uses this in real life...